# Qt, paint image, will this cause memory issue?

Tags: c++, qt

```
//Case 1:
QImage* tImg = new QImage("Some Image Here");
painter->drawImage(x, y, *tImg );
...
delete tImg;

//Case 2:
QImage* tImg = new QImage("Some Image Here");
{
    QImage aImg(*tImg);
    painter->drawImage(x, y, aImg );
}
...
delete tImg;
```

I am trying to load several images in a worker thread and draw them out int the main thread. But I am not sure is it ok to delete the image in the worker thread after drawing them out.

```
//Case 3:
...
//In worker thread
QImage* tImg = new QImage("Some Image Here");
mutex.lock();
matrix.insert(tImg); // matrix is a QList
mutex.unlock();
...
//In main thread
mutex.lock();
foreach(QImage* tImg, matrix)
{
    painter->drawImage(x, y, *tImg);
}
mutex.unlock();
...
//In worker thread
mutex.lock();
matrix.remove(tImg);
delete tImg;
mutex.unlock();
```

Will the above code causing issues? Since the drawImage function is a "pass by const reference". Will this causing any memory issue?

What if `delete tImg` is on another thread? Will it be safe if I use mutex to make sure the `delete tImg` only called after `painter->drawImage(x, y, *tImg );`

Comment: Why don't you just allocate `QImage` on stack?

Comment: I can, I just wonder how the function work to avoid possible bugs in the future.

Comment: This behavior is not documented. We usually assume const reference to be always valid (there is no way to verify if it's not, and it is by design). It is never a good idea to deallocate underlying storage for a reference. And certainly, `QPainter` is not thread-safe. If in doubt, the best way to understand internals of the open-source library is to download and read its source code. That's probably your best bet.

Comment: What about the case 2 in my modified question? If I would like to transfer some QImage loaded in another thread and paint them in the main thread, then deleted them when no longer needed, what's the best approach? If you know please put it as an answer, I would accept that :)

Comment: And QImage seems to be something called copy on write, will that help in my situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual memory management is unnecessary. You should leverage Qt to do it for you. You can pass the image through a signal-slot connection, and use the fact that the value will be automatically copied, and any access to it will be automatically synchronized by Qt.

Here's how you could do it, very simply, letting the compiler do all the hard work of resource management for you:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/imageloader-36265788
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtConcurrent>
```

First, let's have a class with a signal that is the image source. It has a signal that provides the image, of a const reference type, since any copying will be done automatically by Qt if necessary to cross thread boundaries.

```
class ImageSource : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   Q_SIGNAL void hasImage(const QImage & image);
```

A method generates the image, and emits the signal. As long as automatic connections are used with the `hasImage` signal, this method can be run in any thread - safely. In our case, we always run this method from the worker thread, but we could run it from the main thread, too - the only difference would be in performance.

```
   /// This method is thread-safe (ignoring the UB of incrementing a shared int)
   void generate() {
      static auto counter = 0;
      QImage img(128, 128, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
      img.fill(Qt::white);
      QPainter p(&img);
      p.drawText(img.rect(), Qt::AlignCenter, QString::number(counter++));
      p.end();
      emit hasImage(img);
   }
};
```

We'll need an instance of that class, and something to show the image on - say, a `QLabel`:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   ImageSource source;
   QLabel label;
   label.show();
```

We can now connect the `hasImage` to a functor that sets the label's size and sets the image on it. It then immediately runs the image generator again in a worker thread from the global pool. That's handled automatically by `QtConcurrent::run`.

The functor runs in the main thread: this is assured by providing the context parameter to the `connect`: `connect(--, --, context, --)`. The functor runs in `label.thread()`, just as we wish.

```
   QObject::connect(&source, &ImageSource::hasImage, &label, [&](const QImage & image){
      label.setFixedSize(image.size());
      label.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
      QtConcurrent::run(&source, &ImageSource::generate);
   });
```

Since the connection is automatic, the effect of calling the `hasImage` signal results in posting of the slot call to the receiving object (`label`) thread's event queue - here, the queue of the main thread. The event loop picks up the slot call, and executes it. So, even through `hasImage` has been called in a worker thread, the image is automatically copied and delivered to our functor in the main thread.

Finally, we generate the first image to start the process.

```
   QtConcurrent::run(&source, &ImageSource::generate); // generate the first image
   return app.exec();
}
```

The `#include` at the end is needed to provide the implementation of the signal `hasImage` signal, and the metadata describing the `ImageSource` class. It is generated by moc.

```
#include "main.moc"
```

This is complete code, you can paste it into a new project, compile and run; or download the complete project from the github link.

It shows a label that gets its pixmap updated at a rate of approximately 1000/s, on my machine. The application is fully responsive: you can freely move the window, and quit it at any time.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24858047/1329652) for another example of a threaded image loader.