# C++ Qt GUI update

Tags: c++, qt

I am new with Qt so I got stuck with GUI update.
I have 2 classes : `ControlWidget` in main thread and `CameraController` in the separate thread.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    CameraController *cameraController = new CameraController;;
    ControlWidget *main_window = new ControlWidget;
    Thread getImageThread; 
    cameraController->moveToThread(&getImageThread);
    getImageThread.start();
    QTimer get_images_timer;
    QObject::connect(&get_images_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), cameraController, SLOT(onTimerOut()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
    QObject::connect(cameraController, SIGNAL(sendLabel(QImage)), main_window, SLOT(getImage(QImage)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
    QObject::connect(&get_images_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), main_window, SLOT(update()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
    get_images_timer.start(2000);
    app.exec();
    return 0;
}
```

So every 2 seconds I want to get images from camera thread and send them to main thread (that actionally happens, so I have `QImage` at the main_window object). 
Then I want to put this QImage to the cam1 and cam2 `QLabel`. And here I am stuck:

First: when I use `setPixmap()` method the `QLabel.width()` and `QLabel.height()` are different then `image.width()` and `image.height()` or `pixmap.width()` and `pixmap.height()`.

Second: I can not visualize the `QLabel`. If I do `this->ImageLayout->addWidget(cam1)` nothing really happens. `this->update` doesn't help either.

Shall I have an extra worker for GUI Update? What am I doing wrong?

Source code for more information :

CameraController.h

```
class CameraController : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT 
private: 
    CoreApi::InstanceHandle g_hApi;
    CoreApi::DeviceCollectionHandle hDeviceCollection;
    CoreApi::DeviceHandle hDevice;
    CoreApi::CameraPortHandle first_cam;
    Common::FrameHandle frame;
    QPixmap pixmap;
    QImage image;
public: 
    CameraController();
    ~CameraController();
    QLabel outLabel;
public slots:
    void onTimerOut();
signals:
    QImage sendLabel(QImage image);
};
```

CameraController.cpp

```
CameraController::CameraController()
{
    try
    {
        this->g_hApi = CoreApi::Instance::initialize();
        this->hDeviceCollection = this->g_hApi->deviceCollection();
        this->hDevice = hDeviceCollection->device(0);
        this->first_cam = hDevice->cameraPort(0);
        first_cam->autoConfigure();
        first_cam->liveStart();
    }
    catch (GeneralException& e)
    {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

CameraController::~CameraController()
{
}

void CameraController::onTimerOut()
{
    if (this->first_cam->liveFrameReady())
    {
        this->frame = first_cam->liveFrame();
        this->image =  QImage((uchar*)this->frame->buffer()->data(), this->frame->dataType()->width(), this->frame->dataType()->height(), QImage::Format::Format_RGB888);
        this->image = this->image.scaled(QSize(this->image.width()/10, this->image.height()/10));
        std::cout << "width = "<<this->image.width() << "height = " << this->image.height() << std::endl;
        emit sendLabel(this->image.copy());
    }
}
```

ControlWidget.h

```
class ControlWidget :public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QGLCanvas *osCanvas;
    QGridLayout *mainLayout;
    QGridLayout *buttonLayout;
    QVBoxLayout *imageLayout, *settingsLayout;
    QHBoxLayout *controlLayout;
    QListWidget *cameraListWidget, *devicesListWidget;
    QLabel *cameraListLabel, *devicesListLabel, *cameraSettingsLabel, *fpsLabel, *shutterLabel;
    QHBoxLayout *fpsLayout, *shutterLayout;
    QLineEdit *fpsEdit, *shutterEdit;
    QPushButton *saveButton, *saveSettingButton, *applySettingsButton, *chooseFolderButton;
    QTimer* m_timer;
public:
    ControlWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~ControlWidget();
    QLabel *cam1, *cam2;
    QImage *camera_1, *camera_2;
    void createWidgets();
public slots:
    void getImage(QImage new_frame);
    void displayImages();
signals: 
    void images_loaded();
private slots:
    void onTimeout()
    {
        qDebug() << "Worker::onTimeout get called from controlWidget timer and  ?: " << QThread::currentThreadId();
    };
};
```

ControlWidget.cpp

```
ControlWidget::ControlWidget(QWidget *parent)
{
    this->createWidgets();
    this->m_timer = new QTimer;
    connect(this->m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()),this, SLOT(update()));
    m_timer->start(1000);
}

ControlWidget::~ControlWidget()
{
    delete this->mainLayout;
}


void ControlWidget::createWidgets() 
{
    this->imageLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    this->cam1 = new QLabel;
    this->cam2 = new QLabel;
    this->imageLayout->addWidget(cam1);
    this->imageLayout->addWidget(cam2);
    this->setLayout(this->imageLayout);
    this->show();
}

void ControlWidget::displayImages()
{
    QLabel tmp_label ;

    std::cout << "********************************************************************************" << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"  camera height  = " <<this->camera_1->height() << "   camera width = " << this->camera_1->width() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "********************************************************************************" << std::endl;
    QPixmap tmp_pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(this->camera_1->copy());
    std::cout << "PIXMAP WIDTH = " << tmp_pixmap.width() << "Pixmap Height = " << tmp_pixmap.height() <<std::endl;
    std::cout << "LABELWIDTH = "<< tmp_label.width() << "LabelHeight =  "<< tmp_label.height() << std::endl;
    tmp_label.setGeometry(200, 200, tmp_pixmap.width(), tmp_pixmap.height());
    tmp_label.show();
    this->cam1 = &tmp_label;
    this->cam2 = &tmp_label;
    std::cout << "CAM1 Width = " <<this->cam1->width() << std::endl;
    this->imageLayout->addWidget(this->cam1);
    this->imageLayout->addWidget(this->cam2);
}



void ControlWidget::getImage(QImage img)
{
    std::cout << "********************************************************************************" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  img height  = " << img.height() << "   img width = " << img.width() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "********************************************************************************" << std::endl;
    this->camera_1 = &QImage(img);
    this->camera_2 = &QImage(img);
    this->displayImages();
}
```

Comment: Please remove code unnecessary to show the issue. There's lots of unnecessary stuff above.

Comment: "Camera_1=&Qimage(Img)" this is very wrong ! You are taking the address of a temporary variable. You open the door to undefined behavior !

Comment: Basslo, thank you. I'm really beginner with pointers and memory (I came from matlab and python, so it's a little bit tricky for me yet )

Comment: For ideas how to asynchronously pass images from a producer (e.g. a camera or a disk loader) to a consumer (e.g. a widget), see: [answer 1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40002585/1329652), [answer 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40115212/1329652), [answer 3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21253353/1329652), [answer 4](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24858047/1329652).

Comment: [quote] For ideas how to asynchronously pass images from a producer (e.g. a camera or a disk loader) to a consumer (e.g. a widget), see: answer 1, answer 2, answer 3, answer 4. [/quote]
Thank you. I will look through them. This is what I have looked for!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so you have a few design issues here:

1. `tmp_label` is created on the stack, and will be destroyed anyway at the end of your `displayImages` method
2. Each time a new camera frame is received, your are trying to add your QLabels back to your UI with `this->imageLayout->addWidget(this->cam1);`. Add them once when constructing the widget instead, and afterward use `cam1->setPixmap(...)` only.
3. Maybe I missed it, but I don't see where you set your image in the QLabel. This is typically done with `QLabel::setPixmap`

And then:

- Calling `update()` should not be necessary when relying on standard widgets like you do, a QLabel updates automatically when you set its pixmap
- You don't actually need to use `this->` in C++
- I don't know what's under your `Thread` class, but when using QThreads you don't need to pass `Qt::QueuedConnection` argument for a connect, this is done automatically
- To exclude a problem related to how to instantiate your UI or how you use layouts, experiment first with a static Qt Designer .ui based interface
- You can actually easily test the validity of the QPixmap and QImage you read by using `QPixmap::save("image.jpg")` or `QImage::save("image.jpg")`

Comment: Thank you. Just fixed and cam1->setPixmap(...) saved my day. I wonder if I can send void* between threads? if I have a void pointer to some memory sent from one thread to another, shall I care about memory at this pointer?  Also, can I define label ins the constructor, or it will be a bad way in this case?

Comment: I changed createWidgets method

void ControlWidget::createWidgets() 
{
 this->cam1->setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 500);
 this->cam2->setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 500);
 this->cam1->setPixmap(QPixmap());
 this->imageLayout->addWidget(cam1);
 this->imageLayout->addWidget(cam2);
 this->setLayout(this->imageLayout);
 this->show();
}
but it gives me QWindowsGeometry: Unable set geometry message in the console on this->show(). Is there any way to fix this warning? I don't really understand why it happens because I preset geometry. Need I also need to preset a pixmap?

Comment: When using layouts, the layout itself will set your widgets geometry, so you can remove your "setGeometry" actually. Calling "show()" is also typically done in the parent when needed, like in your main, instead of the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @basslo comment, do not do `this->cam1 = &tmp_label;`. When `tmp_label` is destroyed (it is a local variable) it will be removed from the layout it belongs too, so it will never be actually displayed.

Use `this->cam1->setPixmap(...)` instead to assign the new image and define the size policy to expanding on construction to expanding ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4672493/1485885) offers more information about it).

Comment: Thank you! Great! It really helped.